# How to stop execution of cumulative functions if some condition fails in python

Tags: python

How can we stop the execution of function2, function3 when InError variable becomes True in function test in below code.

```
IsError = False
def test():
    global IsError
    print('Test')
    IsError = True
def function1():
    pass
def function2():
    pass
def function3():
    pass

while not IsError:
    print('execute function 1')
    function1()
    print('executing test function')
    test()
    print('execute function 2')
    function2()
    print('execute function 3')
    function3()
```

Comment: can you tell us where your attempt failed? [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/mcve)

Comment: I recommend to use exceptions and try-except blocks.

Comment: Instead of using a while block and setting IsError to True you could use a try-except block and throw an exception when your computation fails.

Comment: As @methk said, it is probably more appropriate to include a raise statement in each of your functions and put all the function calls in a try-except block.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to exit a program when an error occurs you can use `sys.exit()` in your script

```
import sys


IsError = False

def function1():
    try:
        global IsError
        IsError = True
        # if IsError becomes True raise Exception
        if IsError:
            raise Exception
    except Exception:
        sys.exit()  # Quick way to exit a program
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need independent `if`s instead of one `while`:

```
if not IsError:
    print('execute function 1')
    function1()
print('executing test function')
test()
if not IsError:
    print('execute function 2')
    function2()
if not IsError:
    print('execute function 3')
    function3()
```